# ItemsControl bound to ICollectionView doesn't load correct View

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a main view whick looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="Records" />
```

in `ViewModel` of this `View` there's a:

```
public BindableCollection<RecordViewModel> Records { get; private set; }
```

and there's also (empty) `RecordViewModel` and simple `RecordView.xaml`

In this configuration everything's working fine. The view `RecordView` shows automatically for every record I add to `Records` Collection.

But now I'd like to add filtering to it.
So I've created a filter and now need to bind to `ICollectionView` instead of `BindableCollection<RecordViewModel>`.

The deal is that Caliburn.Micro doesn't show any view no more, but instead shows `MyNamespace.RecordViewModel` text in place of where the item's view should be.

How may I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this with Calubrn.Micro's conventions, but you can always use the normal WPF way of doing things, which means that you can use an `ItemTemplate` to tell WPF to use your `RecordView` for each of the items in the list.

Comment: @Steve: You were very close :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it

The view should look like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="Records">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It's working now.

But if there's a shorthand for this - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate">
            <ContentControl x:Name="Records" />
        </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```